# Facebook ShareDialog Limitations

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

Am facing one problem -> Sharing photos on facebook using Facebook Share Dialog (Facebook SDK) and that thing don't require publish action permission.

And everything works perfect until i share more then 6 photos. Its not working for more photos. So i want to know that is there any limitations from facebook side or from SDK that i can share 6 photos programatically (Bulk)

Here is the code Sample that am following :

```
for (int index = 0; index < mArryLstPhotos.size(); index++) {

                String pathofBmp = saveImageToExternalStorage(mArryLstPhotos.get(index), mImagesPath.get(index));
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathofBmp.contains("file:///") ?
                        pathofBmp.replace("file://", "")
                        : pathofBmp);

                if (bitmap != null && photos.size() < 6)
                    photos.add(new SharePhoto.Builder()
                            .setBitmap(bitmap)
                            .build());
            }
```

And then showing it using  :

```
if (shareDialog.canShow(content)) {  
 shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

-> People can share a combination of photos and videos from your app to Facebook with the Share Dialog. Note the following:

People need the native Facebook for Android app installed, version 71 or higher.
Photos must be less than 12MB in size.
Videos must be less than 12MB in size.
People can share a maximum of 6 photos and videos at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so finally found an answer.

-> People can share a combination of photos and videos from your app to Facebook with the Share Dialog. Note the following:

People need the native Facebook for Android app installed, version 71 or higher.
Photos must be less than 12MB in size.
Videos must be less than 12MB in size.
People can share a maximum of **6 photos** and videos at a time.

For more detail : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

[image]